# How to install cyrtimes.sty for Texmaker with installed texlive-full at Linux Mint (Ubuntu)

Tags: texlive, installing, texmaker, ubuntu

I had some troubles with TeX packages installation for my minimal configuration, so I decided to install `texlive-full`. After that I can't build my document anymore because of missed very basic package `cyrtimes.sty`.

Beginning of my document:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cyrtimes}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
```

Texmaker Log fragment:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `cyrtimes.sty' not found.
```

To install `cyrtimes.sty` you usually need to do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install scalable-cyrfonts-tex
```

But `apt` recommends to remove `texlive-full` before doing that.

How can I install `cyrtimes.sty` keeping `texlive-full` at my computer?

- texlive-full version: 2013.20140215-1
- Texmaker version: 4.1

Comment: It's really strange that a package meant for TeX disallows having installed `texlive-full`. Ask the maintainer.

Comment: I've solved this for my case by using [great stub with cyrillic-related styles](https://github.com/w495/dsmts-diploma-text) -- it doesn't require such dependencies.